# PHP - Count string for occurrence which is printed

Tags: php, url, count, query-string

I've got the following...

```
 <a href='Count.php?count=Red'><
```

but how would i make it so it counts more than one colour?

```
 <a href='Count.php?count=Red, Green, Blue'><
```

doesnt work, nor does replacing the , with &&, any ideas?

Here's the PHP code that does the counting:

```
<?php 
$lineNumber=0; 
$handle = fopen('shapeStorage.txt', 'r'); 
if ($handle) 
    { 
    while (($line = fgets($handle))!== false) 
        { 
        $lines[$lineNumber] = $line; 
        $lineNumber++; 
        } 
    } 
else 
    { 
    echo 'error, error, high voltage';
    } 
for($n=0; $n<sizeof($lines); $n++)
    { 
    if(strstr($lines[$n], $_GET["count"])) $colourCount++; 
    } 
echo '<h2>There are '.$colourCount.' '.$_GET["count"].' shape(s) stored within the site.</h2>'; 
?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to count how many times each colour occurs or the number of colours?

Comment: how many times it occurs within a text file.

Comment: You mean you want to count how many times each word occurs in the file?

Comment: Then what is the purpose of the href? Is it to specify which colours to count?

Comment: beacause it takes it to another page to tell you how many their are of a specific colour... ill post the php side

Comment: Why did you edit your question with some garbled text like this?

Comment: @itsols Rollback done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you should do:

```
<a href='Count.php?count=Red-Green-Blue'>
```

Now in PHP you can split it up using the hyphen like this:

```
$Colours = explode("-", $_GET["count"]);
```

Now use the $Colours array in your code.

This is not the solution to your counting algorithm, but it is the answer to your question on how to include multiple colours.

Hope this helps.

Comment: where do i place the $colours line?

Answer (score 1):

Use array syntax for the variable name:

```
<a href='Count.php?count[]=Red&count[]=Green&count[]=Blue'>
```

Then on the PHP side:

```
$colors = $_GET['count'];
print_r($colors);
/* OUTPUTS
Array
(
    [0] => Red
    [1] => Green
    [2] => Blue
)
*/
```